# Using CodeIgniter Active Record statements

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm looking for a way to use Active Record in CodeIgniter to build my query.

My current code is this:

```
$this->db->   like('responsible', $user->id);
$this->db->or_like('accountable', $user->id);
$this->db->or_like('consulted',   $user->id);
$this->db->or_like('informed',    $user->id);

// Get the tasks, but only with the correct start or end date
$tasks = $this->db->get_where('level_' . $this->config->item('answer_level'), array('date_end' => $offset, 'ccode' => $user->country));

// Check if tasks exist
if($tasks->num_rows() > 0){
    // Tasks have been found that should have been finished!
    echo $tasks->num_rows() . " tasks found for " . $user->first_name . " that should have been finished!\n";
    $last_month_tasks = $tasks->result();
}

unset($tasks);
```

Which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`level_3`)
WHERE `date_start` =  -5
AND `ccode` =  'GB'
AND  `responsible`  LIKE '%5%'
OR  `accountable`  LIKE '%5%'
OR  `consulted`  LIKE '%5%'
OR  `informed`  LIKE '%5%'
```

But I need it to produce this SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`level_3`)
WHERE  `date_start` = -5
AND  `ccode` =  'GB'
AND (
`responsible` LIKE  '%5%'
    OR  `accountable` LIKE  '%5%'
    OR  `consulted` LIKE  '%5%'
    OR  `informed` LIKE  '%5%'
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord does not support nesting of queries and clauses.
You have to do it manually like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('level_' . $this->config->item('answer_level'));
$this->db->where(array('date_end' => $offset, 'ccode' => $user->country));
$this->db->where("(responsible LIKE '%5%' OR accountable LIKE '%5%' OR consulted LIKE '%5%' OR informed LIKE '%5%')");
$tasks = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to edit the SQL for fix a few things in your answer though.